# CakePHP 404 page is not using layout set in AppController

Tags: cakephp, layout, http-status-code-404, cakephp-1.3

I have 2 versions of my site, (depending on what domain was used to access it).
Each version is a completely different brand.

In my AppController I have something like this:

```
// use default layout for posh site
// use cheap layout for cheap site
function beforeFilter() 
{
    parent::beforeFilter(); 

    if(isCheap())
    {
        $this->layout = 'cheap';
    }      
}
```

So now, when someone goes to my site via posh.com they get the posh layout, if someone goes to my site via cheap.com they get the cheap layout.

However, if someone hits the 404 page on the cheap site, it does not load the cheap layout, it loads the default layout. So from their perspective, suddenly they will appear to be in a different site.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems work, I had to duplicate the logic though, which I do not like.

I created the file `app/error.php` containing:

```
class AppError extends ErrorHandler 
{ 
    function error404($params) 
    { 
        if(isCheap())
        {
            $this->controller->layout = "cheap";
        } 
        parent::error404($params); 
    } 
}
```